google chat disable url preview - not messages, not gmail
How do you disable the automated link preview in google chat?
This is the garbage chat functionality that used to be Google Meet, but was shoved into gmail.  This is NOT urls in email messages.  This is NOT the google messages app on an android phone.
Every time I type a URL in a Google Chat message, google chat fills up the rest of my window with a preview of the website.  I don't want that.  It's not helpful - even if it's useful to someone else in the world it is harmful to my user experience.  I want to find the configuration option that turns this functionality off.  How do I do that?

How do you disable the automated link preview in google chat?

Link previews from websites can be turned on or off:

Open Google Messages .

At the top right, tap your profile photo or icon and then Settings and then Automatic previews.

Turn off Show all previews.
Optional: To turn off previews when you send or get a link in a conversation, tap Show only web link previews.



Source: Change Messages notifications and settings - Google Messages
